# How to generate DropDownListFor text and value field as table column name's?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing the Issue where I have to generate a ddL from database in which value and text fields are the table column name's not row data.

like I have a table Employee in which my column name's are EmployeeId, EmplyeeName, EmpDept, EmpDesig, etc....

so how to populate dlL like this

```
text            value    
EmployeeId       EmployeeId
EmplyeeName      EmplyeeName
EmpDept          EmpDept
EmpDesig         EmpDesig
```

Comment: Have you considered using UNPIVOT (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx)?

Comment: This link https://dotnetfiddle.net/q4CfqA may help you

Comment: Azim try to understand the question please